# Ext.data.JsonP.request always going to failed function?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I am doing application in Extjs, i am calling Ext.data.JsonP.request. **In below code url path will come dynamically generate by appending name to base url of pdf**. But Here i am hard coded. I am passing this url and testing jsonp request. if this url returns success i can write code success logic else failure, but here always going to failure method. also i have tried Ajax.request but no use. Some time i will get pdf path but that pdf is not in server that time i need showcase alert message like pdf is not found. **Can tell me how can achieve this one? is it possible by calling jsonp request or any other method?** Thank you

**here is my code:**

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
            url: 'http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume10/mannor09a/mannor09a.pdf',
            method: 'GET',
            params: {
                //fileID: feed_id, //this.form.getComponent('file').value,
            },
            failure: function () {
                alert('failed  !');
            },
            success: function () {
                alert('success!');
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that you need ajax to get pdf file? If you want to display this file to user, you can just put direct link to this file (without ajax or other tricks) and browser will show it.
Hard to understand, what do you want to get in the success function.

My recommendation to use plain link (you still can generate it dynamically to user)
 
    `<a href="http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume10/mannor09a/mannor09a.pdf">Link</a>`
against using JSONP in this situation :)